# High order component and redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

i have a hoc and redux in my app page (userpage).

At the end of my component i have:

```
...

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(state)
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withAuth(User))
```

i do `console.log(props)` at the begining of render, but... at the first render i got the state of redux, but at the second render, i got this:

[image: Console.log of state (mapStateToProps)]

why? the reducer that i'm running at this time is:

```
case 'GET-USERS':
      const ami = state.usersOnline.filter(e => e === action.user._id);
      if(ami.length === 0){
        state = {...state, usersOnline: state.usersOnline.concat(action.user)}
      }
      break;
```

I need some help!

when i added the solution of lucas, i got this error:

[image: Undefined error]

Comment: Is your reducer returning the state after it updates it/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your reducer returning the state?

e.g. `return state` after your switch statement?

Comment: wow!!! this is the issue, but, i got 4444444 console.logs (multirender) why???

Comment: The state will be defined with its initial value until the first action is processed by the reducer.

Answer (score 1):

Your `mapStateToProps` method must receive the redux state as argument and return a subset of the components props. Therefore, the return value of the function must be an object, but you don't return anything.

Change it to something like:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(state)
  return { /* component props */ };
}
```

Comment: yeah, but i got undefined state :/

Comment: What do you mean with that?

Comment: The error appear at the second render, when i receive data, you know?